# angularjs : how to broadcast between services ? is it possible to broadcast a variable from a service and use it in another service?

Tags: angularjs, service, broadcast

I'm not so new in angularjs(two week experience). is it possible to broadcast  data from a service and use that data  in another service. i just want to pass data between services not controller if it's possible. i know it's possible between controllers and from service to controllers .

Comment: Why not inject ServiceA into ServiceB and then call ServiceA's methods from ServiceB?

Comment: i know that but i want know more about broadcast and emit .

Comment: yes or no . if no then why no and if yes then how yes

Comment: I think that broadcasting only works with controllers that have scope. The broadcasting happens between layers of inheritance of scope. To share data with services, you simply inject the service into another service or controller.

Comment: what about rootScope ? i can broadcast from service to a controller .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible by injecting $rootScope into both services and adding the normal $emit and $on calls. Here is a plunker demonstrating what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/6O9qEDCWoauucuDzxygn

This smells like a poor design to me though..

Comment: obviously this is bad design . as per my knowledge  emit passes data upward but in your example  it passes data downward !!! why so ?

Comment: it is neither up or down in this case.. $rootScope is sending the event, and it is being received on $rootScope.. $broadcast would probably work too